# Reverse carousel javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, carousel, reverse

I have the following code and I need to create a button to reverse the moving direction everytime the user clicks on it.

I need some help, please.

```
var div_width = 87;
var div_count = 15;
var reset_offset = div_width * (div_count -1);

function init() {

// Set initial position - note that the first div will
// be off the lefthand side
for(i=0;i<div_count;i++) {
    var foo = document.getElementById('fooObject' + i);
    foo.style.left = ''+(i*div_width)+'px';

 }

 doMove();
}

function doMove() {
 for(i=0;i<div_count;i++) {
    var foo = document.getElementById('fooObject' + i);
    var left = parseInt(foo.style.left);
    foo.style.left = '' + (left+1) + 'px';
    if (left >= reset_offset) {
        foo.style.left = '' + (-div_width) + 'px';
    }
 }
setTimeout(doMove, 20);
}

init();
```

Thank you!

More detailed here:
    http://jsfiddle.net/usjpzcbq/